# Changes in grub configuration file not allowingg to login in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: grub2

I have changed the following entry in grub configuration file as follows:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

After this change I am unable to login in ubuntu 14.04. Whenever I am login it is coming to same login window.

please suggest me what should I do now. I have tried to loging through window that comes after pressing ctrl+alt+f1 but not able to login through that as well.

Comment: Have you run `sudo update-grub` after changing `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in the `/etc/default/grub`?

Answer (score 0):

Boot your computer. When the GRUB menu (the one that lets you select your OS) shows up, select Ubuntu and press 'e'. If this menu does not appear, keep pressing Shift right after the computer boots until it does.

After pressing 'e' on Ubuntu you will see some kind of text editor. Find the line that begins with `linux` and go to its end. Remove `nomodeset` from the end of the line and press F10. Ubuntu should boot.

Open a terminal window and run the following commands:

`sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

Change the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`.

Save the file and exit. Then run:

`sudo update-grub`

Your system should be fine. Reboot and test it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is working now.

However I had tried nomodset as a may be solution to the problem of freezing of ubuntu during booting which is still a problem and exactly same as the one mentioned in the below link 

http://askubuntu.com/questions/714298/ubuntu-freezing-while-booting-after-working-for-some-time

Can you please help in this? Thanks in advance.